# Image don't stay on same position when maximize on tabcontrol in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio, tabcontrol

When i maximize the form the image don't stay on same place regarding the tabcontrol.
[image before maximize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTGDm.png)

[image before maximize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4I0J.png)

Comment: The image with the red border appears to be in exactly the same position in both images (relative to the top left corner of the form)

Comment: You have to anchor you image (Properties -> Anchor) by your needs following the base corner (on your logic)

Comment: @user20716902 i understand what you mean, but i need to have the same position relative to the tabcontrol. If you check the tabcontrol image, the "red border image" is on a diferent position

Comment: @Colatra93, perhaps you can add a third example image to the question?, showing where you would expect the image to be when maximised, this will help me understand.